# docker and mysql: Got an error reading communication packets

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-api, prisma, prisma-graphql

I have a problem with connectivity in docker. I use an official mysql 5.7 image and [Prisma](https://www.prismagraphql.com/) server. When I start it via prisma cli, that uses `docker compose` underneath (described [here](https://www.prismagraphql.com/docs/reference/clusters/docker-aira9zama5#configuration-with-docker-compose)) everything works.

But I need to start this containers programmatically via docker api and in this case connections from app are dropped with `[Note] Aborted connection 8 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'root' host: '164.20.10.2' (Got an error reading communication packets)`.

So what I doo:

1. Creating a bridge network:

   ```
   const network = await docker.network.create({
   Name: manifest.name + '_network',
   IPAM: {
     "Driver": "default",
     "Config": [
       {
         "Subnet": "164.20.0.0/16",
         "IPRange": "164.20.10.0/24"
       }
     ]
   }});
   ```
2. Creating mysql container and attaching it to network

   ```
   const mysql = await docker.container.create({
   Image: 'mysql:5.7',
   Hostname: manifest.name + '-mysql',
   Names: ['/' + manifest.name + '-mysql'],
   NetworkingConfig: {
     EndpointsConfig: {
       [manifest.name + '_network']: {
         Aliases: [manifest.name + '-mysql']
       }
     }
   },
   Restart: 'always',
   Args: [
     "mysqld",
     "--max-connections=1000",
     "--sql-mode=ALLOW_INVALID_DATES,ANSI_QUOTES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,HIGH_NOT_PRECEDENCE,IGNORE_SPACE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO,NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES,NO_DIR_IN_CREATE,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_FIELD_OPTIONS,NO_KEY_OPTIONS,NO_TABLE_OPTIONS,NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,PIPES_AS_CONCAT,REAL_AS_FLOAT,STRICT_ALL_TABLES,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ANSI,DB2,MAXDB,MSSQL,MYSQL323,MYSQL40,ORACLE,POSTGRESQL,TRADITIONAL"
   ],
   Env: [
     'MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret'
   ]
   });

   await network.connect({
      Container: mysql.id
   });
   await mysql.start();
   ```
3. Then I wait Mysql to boot, create needed databases and needed `Prisma` containers from `prismagraphql/prisma:1.1` and start them. App server resolves mysql host correctly, but connections are dropped by mysql.

Telnet from app container to mysql container in 3306 port responds correctly:

```
J
5.7.21U;uH  Kem']#45T]2mysql_native_password
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried to increase `max_allowed_packet` ?

Answer (score 1):

Check the below:

- max_allowed_packets
- wait_timeout
- net_read_timeout

Also monitor MySQL process list during the issue to identify timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try some wait, it could be possible that application try to connect to mysql server before its ready to accept connection. To test this, add some wait on startup or run mysql followed by application as different deployments.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to add `--wait-timeout=28800` (or higher number) into MySQL arguments:

```js
Args: [
  "mysqld",
  "--max-connections=1000",
  "--sql-mode=ALLOW_INVALID_DATES,ANSI_QUOTES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,HIGH_NOT_PRECEDENCE,IGNORE_SPACE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO,NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES,NO_DIR_IN_CREATE,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_FIELD_OPTIONS,NO_KEY_OPTIONS,NO_TABLE_OPTIONS,NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,PIPES_AS_CONCAT,REAL_AS_FLOAT,STRICT_ALL_TABLES,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ANSI,DB2,MAXDB,MSSQL,MYSQL323,MYSQL40,ORACLE,POSTGRESQL,TRADITIONAL",
  "--wait-timeout=28800" // 28800 sec = 8 hours
],
```

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout

But maybe it's wiser to find out what is the root cause for idle connections.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Mac Apple Silicon. Same issue appeared on M1 M2 M3 arm chip.
Just have to disable "Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon" in Docker configuration and it works fine.